# Find all classes in a js file with nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to Find all classes in a js file, and add it into an array with nodeJs.
Now i have in console //opened **but i want** //opened, carambar (all results)

See my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var regExp = /addClass\([\s'"]*(.*?)[\s'"]*\)/gm;
var res;
var file, match;
fs.readFile('assets/js/src/menu.js', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    file = ''+data;
    match = regExp.exec(file);
    console.log(file);
    console.log('match: '+match[1],' type: '+typeof match, 'match length '+match.length);
});
```

and the file in which I seek:

```
if (matchMedia('(max-width: 1023px)').matches) {
    //console.log("under 1023px");
    // Mega Menu Mobile
    // Open main-menu
    jQuery(".button__menu-open").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(".menu__mobile").addClass("opened");
        jQuery(".menu__mobile").addClass("carambar");
        jQuery("html, body").addClass("menu-mobile--active");
    });
    // Close menu
    jQuery(".button__menu-close").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(".menu__mobile").removeClass("opened");
        jQuery("html, body").removeClass("menu-mobile--active");
    });

}
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use while(match) to find all occurrences

```
var fs = require('fs');
var regExp = /addClass\([\s'"]*(.*?)[\s'"]*\)/gm;
var res;
var file, match;
fs.readFile('b.js', (err, data) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   file = ''+data;
   while(match = regExp.exec(file)){
     console.log('match: '+match[1],' type: '+typeof match, 'match length '+match.length);
   }
});
```

Which display :
match: opened  type: object match length 2
match: carambar  type: object match length 2
match: menu-mobile--active  type: object match length 2